# Missing link - URL filtering? Limits on #/length of links? false positive?

Tags: bug, status-declined

In [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/whats-the-difference-between-the-levels-of-weather-sealing-on-dslrs-e-g-50d-vs/2987#2987) I posted a link to a [Nikonos article on mir.com.my](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/htmls/models/htmls/nikonos.htm).  The link worked on the preview, but isn't visible in the answer itself.  The URL is still visible when you edit the page, and the preview continues to function.  You can see the link text on the [view source](https://photo.stackexchange.com/revisions/0cdb7e85-6aed-44e8-b84e-77628b7a474f/view-source) link of the revisions.

I've tried both standard <a href="..."> and markdown syntax, no difference.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4):

You had an unclosed `<a>` in your post. I closed it, and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, I can't see it when I look at the [revisions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/2987/revisions) for that post. Don't know how that helps but ...

And I think your first link above is broken - or maybe it's just I don't have the rep to edit your answer.

Comment: sorry; should be fixed now, I didn't mean to point to the 'edit' link.  I hadn't checked the revisions link, but that does help: it's visible in the view source link.